# Convert letsencrypt pem to p12

Tags: certificate, lets-encrypt, p12

I can't convert LetsEncrypt .pem files to .p12

```
openssl pkcs12 -export -out cert.p12 -inkey /path/privkey.pem -in /path/cert.pem -passout pass: -nokeys
```

On https://www.sslshopper.com/ssl-converter.html it is converted OK, with **privkey.pem** and **cert.pem**, but on my PC I recive bad p12:

*Could not parse invalid or corrupted data.*